# Two element's background-color within a nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add an effect of two elements within a div. I tried selecting their id(and also some other way) but is not working as expected. Maybe I am unsuccessful because of my not having deep knowledge of HTML/CSS.

Here is a sample of what I tried recently-

```
<style>
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 890px;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}
nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: .4em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BBB;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #CCC;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#menuBar{
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #4CAF50;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

</head>
    <body id="top" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
        <nav>
            <div id="menuBar">
                <div id="logo">nMess</div>
                <label for="drop" class="toggle menu">Menu</label> <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="homepage">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bazarExchange">Bazar Exchange</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bazarValidate">Bazar Validate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="profile">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a class="alertBtn" href="logout">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screeshot what does it look like right now-
[image]

But I want this-
[image]

*Note: I don't want the whole background's color gray, want gray within the white background.*

Comment: @Isac, I could not find anything following your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1: use `clearfix` with floats

You've put `background-color: #2D2D2D;` on `#menuBar`, but it collapses to zero height - since all it's children are floated or hidden. You should use clearfix to avoid it (note `.clearfix` class on `#menuBar`):

```css
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 890px;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}
nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: .4em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BBB;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #CCC;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#menuBar{
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #4CAF50;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "."; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body id="top" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
  <nav>
    <div id="menuBar" class="clearfix">
      <div id="logo">nMess</div>
      <label for="drop" class="toggle menu">Menu</label> <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="homepage">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="bazarValidate">Bazar Validate</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a class="alertBtn" href="logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

### Solution 2: use `linear-gradient`

You can use linear gradient to make multicolor backgrounds (note `.gradient` class on `nav`):

```css
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 890px;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}
nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: .4em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BBB;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #CCC;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #4CAF50;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 10%, #2d2d2d 10%, #2d2d2d 90%, #fff 90%, #fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<body id="top" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
  <nav class="gradient">
    <div id="menuBar">
      <div id="logo">nMess</div>
      <label for="drop" class="toggle menu">Menu</label> <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
      <ul class="menu clearfix">
        <li><a href="homepage">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="bazarValidate">Bazar Validate</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a class="alertBtn" href="logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: The first one fulfils my requirement better.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the HTML element nav for your background like so:

```
nav {
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
```

And if you still want a white border on the top and bottom you can add one like so:

```
nav {
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/onjxwz88/

Hello there!

Here's what you are looking to do exactly!

HTML:

```
       <nav>
            <div id="menuBar">
                <ul class="menu">

                    <li> <div id="logo">nMess</div>
                                    <label for="drop" class="toggle menu">Menu</label> <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
                    </li>
<div class="right">

                    <li><a href="homepage">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bazarExchange">Bazar Exchange</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bazarValidate">Bazar Validate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="profile">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a class="alertBtn" href="logout">Logout</a></li></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 890px;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}

#menuBar{
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
      color:#fff;
}
nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: .4em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BBB;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #CCC;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
nav ul {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width:100%;
        background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
nav ul div.right{
  float:right;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #4CAF50;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image]